# If there exists an alpha that meets a certain condition show that $(na_n)$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I was seeing this interesting generalization, since it will show the case when the sequence is decreasing, that is, when alpha $= 0$, I understand almost the entire proof except for the last part, I do not understand how to get the fact that $r_n = b_n - s_n$ with the fact that $b_n$ is increasing and the $s_n$ are bounded since the series converges, how does that show that $r_n$ is convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sum_n a_n$ converges $s_n$ converges as well. Since $b_n$ is increasing its limit can be finite or $\infty$. If the limit is infinite it proves that $r_n \to \infty$ and then $\frac1n = o(a_n)$ which implies that $a_n$ diverges.